# Asp.net project's property "Web \ Use Local IIs Web Server" effecting other team members

Tags: asp.net, git, github, asp.net-mvc-4, git-svn

I just change the Properties of my asp.net project like given below.

```
Property\Web\Use Local IIS Web Server \ Project Url: http://domain.com
Property\Web\Use Local IIS Web Server \ Override application root URL: http://domain.com
```

But after the commit in svn. The changes got reflected in other team members's project. Because these settings are in project file of application.

I also can't ignore this project file from commit. Because in this case other member won't be having proper update of my work from svn.

How can i keep these setting only personal to me, while keep committing the project file of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep those changes in the project file you'll inevitably cause problems with versioning within SVN, which is not the best way to go. One approach is to leave the project settings as they are (I'm assuming that you're using IIS and everyone else is using Cassini or IIS Express) but create a website within your local IIS. Then, instead of running the application via F5 or CTRL-F5, manually attach the debugger to the ASP.NET worker process via `Debug > Attach to process`.